# How to properly save data across Activities. savedInstanceState always appears to be null

Tags: android

I have 2 activities A and B.

1. I call activity B from activity A using startActivity(B);
2. I do some operations in B and call back activity A using startActivity(A);

I have noticed that instance variables in class A are cleared (reinitialized). Is using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` a correct way to save these variables before A gets stopped?

In my `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of class A, I try to retrieve the data previously saved by `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`. However the variable `savedInstanceState` is always null and I can't retrieve any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return to your previous activity, you must call finish() on activity B, and then intercept it in activity A with onActivityResult().

Is that what you tried to accomplish?

Comment: Also note that your previous instance of activity A is not always destroyed, only paused. So the instance state will be there. The onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) will not be called, only onResume (followed by onActivtyResult).

Comment: I logged the operation of my app and noticed that when doing what I described, both the `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onCreate()` of activity A get called. It's just the Bundle passed to `onCreate()` is always null.

No I'm not trying to get any data from activity B to activity A. I'm just trying to preserve data in A since they get reinitialized when I go A -> B -> A.

Comment: But if you do as you described, you're not calling back the original activity A. Instead you're starting a new instance of activity A, thus the entire lifecycle run for that new instance. Hence the onCreate() is called and you haven't saved instance state for that new activity A. Although you don't need to get data from activity B, you must call finish() to go back to acativty A, and then handle the onResume().

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. So calling `startActivity()` will start a completely new instance of an activity so that the savedStateInstance will always be null.

I've solved the problem by saving data to `SharedPreferences` which works quite fine. Although it might be a bit of an overkill. Is there a simpler way to do what I want?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. And yes, a simpler way exists. When you have done your stuff in activity B, call `this.finish()`. That will return the control to the previous instance of activity A. The instance state will be there (assuming the activity wasn't destroyed by the OS). If you need to do something when returning, you can override `onResume()` and `onStart()` methods. I'll recomend you to have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html), sections **Starting an Activity** and **Managing the Activity Lifecycle**.